# Why is there a discrepancy in the reputation reported on this profile page?

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page

I was looking at [another user's profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2481453/informatimago?tab=topactivity) and noticed a discrepancy in the reported reputation. The graph on the Activity tab shows a reputation of 189, but the number reported in the top left corner for reputation is only 89.

[image]

Looking at their daily reputation change log, 89 is reported at the top, but the individual log entries add up to 188. This makes sense with respect to the graph; a user starting with 1 rep should have 189 rep after a change of +188.

Why don't the main reputation graph and the reported reputation score agree? Is there some sort of -100 point penalty that would be reflected in the total reputation score, but would not show up on the daily reputation log and graph, or is this a bug?

Comment: One of the measures that's taken if a post is flagged as spam is the offending account loses 100 reputation, but this isn't reflected in the user's reputation summary for reasons, so that's probably what happened here. Is this something that a 10k user can confirm is the case?

Comment: @Hoppeduppeanut that’s exactly what happened to this user, several years ago a post of theirs was flagged as rude and they received a red flag penalty. And the -100 is not visible to anyone but moderators and the user themselves; the post that was flagged has been deleted, after all.

Comment: That -100 reputation penalty *should* still be reflected on the reputation time-series plot, though...